# org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory cannot be cast to org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory

Tags: spring, jms, rabbitmq

I am getting the following error when I run rabbitmq and jms Spring Project together.

> ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path
>   resource [com/thys/michels/service_core/amqp/AmqpConfiguration.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate
>   com.thys.michels.service_core.amqp.AmqpConfiguration.rabbitTemplate()]
>   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory cannot be
>   cast to org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory cannot be
>   cast to org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory

Any suggestions why?

Comment: which versions of spring, rabbitmq are you using ? could you post your configuration too ?

Comment: Config is very long, hope this helps:<org.springframework-version>3.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version><dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>

Comment: and your spring configuration ?

Comment: JMS Bean:
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws Exception {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(environment.getProperty("jms.broker.url"));
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both my JMS and RabbitMQ class had a connectionFactory class called connectionFactory and so the connectionfactory for JMS was used initialized for RabbitMQ config.

JMS class

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws Exception {
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
            activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(environment.getProperty("jms.broker.url"));
            return new CachingConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
        }
```

RabbitMQ class

```
@Bean
       public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
                CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
                cachingConnectionFactory.setUsername(environment.getProperty("amqp.broker.username"));
                cachingConnectionFactory.setPassword(environment.getProperty("amqp.broker.password"));
                cachingConnectionFactory.setHost(environment.getProperty("amqp.broker.host"));
                cachingConnectionFactory.setPort(environment.getProperty( "amqp.broker.port", Integer.class));
                // cachingConnectionFactory.setPort(60705);
                return cachingConnectionFactory;
            }
```

just changed the connectionFactory names and it worked.